# Double axis chart in jqplot

Tags: jqplot

Is it possible to have double axis chart using jqplot

Can anyone please share the example for the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible.

---

#### Code example :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.jqplot('chart1', [
            [54551.94,15192.79,37937.26,11417.67,11799.59,18377.53,49207.82,168235.42,16654.29,62145.78],
            [132.19,2.99,6.09,50.38,1.44,4.41,25.25,3.37,68.60,2.14]
        ], {
        seriesDefaults : {
            renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions : {  
                highlightMouseOver : true,
                barWidth : 10
            }
        },  
        legend : {
            show : true,
            placement : 'outsideGrid'
        },                  
      
        axes : {                 
            xaxis : {
                renderer : $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions : {
                  angle : 45    
                },
                ticks : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
            },
            yaxis : {
                label : 'axis1',
                renderer : $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer                        
            },
            y2axis : {
                label : 'axis2'                      
            }
        },
        series : [{
            yaxis : 'yaxis',
            label : 'dataForAxis1'
        }, {
            yaxis : 'y2axis',
            label : 'dataForAxis2'
        }]
    });
});
```

---

#### JSFiddle example :

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6kCw6/22/)**

---

#### Documentation :

[**See here**](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/rotated-tick-labels.php) for the reference.

Look the third example from the top.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. A starting example can be :

```
var yaxis_data = [1,2,3,4];
var y2axis_data = [2,4,6];
var myjqplot = $.jqplot('chart1', [yaxis_data, y2axis_data], {
  series: [
   { yaxis: "yaxis" },
   { yaxis: "y2axis" }
  ]
});
```

**Edit :** See [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Series) for further explanations about Series